# Should An Actvity Pass Fields To Fragment Or Should The Fragment Initialize It?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `ListFragment` that's using a DAO object. The DAO object queries a DB and returns a list of strings that I will display in the `ListView`. My question is - should the activity pass the DAO object to the fragment, or should the fragment initialize it on its own?

Activity:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcable("dao", myDao);
FragmentClass frag = new FragmentClass();
frag.setArguments(bundle);
```

Or in Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 myDao = new MyDao(getActivity());
}
```

Comment: It depends on the life time of the fragment. If the fragment is not to be replaced, removed or changed all the time, then go ahead and use the fragment for initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first case `"Passing field to fragment"` is better. As @Campiador commented, if your case is to retain the `FragmentClass` for all the time then you can initialise the fields from fragment

Activity:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcable("dao", myDao);
FragmentClass frag = new FragmentClass();
frag.setArguments(bundle);
```

Fragment :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 MyDao mDao = getArguments().getParcelable("dao");   
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I will leave the answer unmarked for awhile to encourage more answers, but if nothing else comes of it I will mark yours.